# Put oneline command into alias

Tags: linux, bash, alias

I can't put this command into a linux alias.

```
du --max-depth=1 | sort -nr | awk ' BEGIN { split("KB,MB,GB,TB", Units, ","); } { u = 1; while ($1 >= 1024) { $1 = $1 / 1024; u += 1 } $1 = sprintf("%.1f %s", $1, Units[u]); print $0; } '
```

I've tried in multiple ways but a I only get multiple syntax errors. I try to escape $ sign, put " in the begin and end but it doesn't works.

Comment: To quote the manpage, a quote the predates 1996: `For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions.` . Use a function.

Comment: Now I'm curious about the "almost" in that statement :)

Answer (score 4):

Do not bother with aliases.  They have been effectively deprecated for over 2 decades.  It is trivial to use a function.  Put this in your startup scripts:

```
foo() { du --max-depth=1 | sort -nr | awk  ... ; }
```

Comment: It doesn't works.  - $ foo() { du --max-depth=1 | sort -nr | awk ' BEGIN { split("KB,MB,GB,TB", Units, ","); } { u = 1; while ($1 >= 1024) { $1 = $1 / 1024; u += 1 } $1 = sprintf("%.1f %s", $1, Units[u]); print $0; } '
>

Comment: It appears a ">" sign waiting for some entry .. but I don't know what it expect.

Comment: You need to close the brackets.  After the awk command, you need `;}`

Comment: That is, the `}` inside the single quote is a part of the awk program.  After the single quote, you should add either a newline or a semi-colon, and then close the function definition with `}`